# Powershell parsing json error, how to choose endpoint?

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, scripting

So I made a script (as generic as I could) to download and install Datadog to my system... The intention is that I want to be able to pass in a version to the powershell script that will download that specific version to my system but I am having issues matching the values ... Would love to know what im doing wrong

Versions (Json) are here [VersionsLink](https://s3.amazonaws.com/ddagent-windows-stable/installers.json)

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
    This PowerShell script is designed to install the Specific Datadog agent seamlessly on windows

    .PARAMETER APIKey
    The API Key for your datadog installation. Contact support if you don't have one!

    .PARAMETER Location
    Where the MSI should be dropped. Defaults to C:\Windows\temp

    .PARAMETER Hostname
    Name of the host. Defaults to the Windows hostname

    .PARAMETER  SpecificVersion
    Version of Datadog to install

    .PARAMETER Tags
    Tags to assign.

    .EXAMPLE
    .\Datadog-Installer.ps1 -APIKey INSERTKEYHERE -Tags MyTag1,MyTag2
#>
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]   $APIKey,
    [string]   $SpecificVersion,

    [ValidateScript ( { Test-Path $_ } ) ]
    [string]   $Location = "C:\Windows\Temp",
    [string]   $Hostname = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
    [string[]] $Tags
)
begin{
    $MSI = "$location\ddog.msi"
    If ( Test-path $MSI ) {
        Remove-Item $MSI -Force
    }
}
process{

Write-Output "Getting versions JSON"
$InstallerJsonUrl ="https://s3.amazonaws.com/ddagent-windows-stable/installers.json"
$Req = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $InstallerJsonUrl

Write-Output "Calculating latest version"
$VersionsObject = $Req.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$VersionStrings = $VersionsObject| Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select Name

$Versions = @()
ForEach ($Version in $VersionStrings){
    $Versions += [version] $Version.Name
}

$ChosenVersion = $Versions -eq $SpecificVersion
Write-Output "Collecting Datadog Version $($ChosenVersion.ToString())"
$TargetMSI = $VersionsObject.$($ChosenVersion.toString()).amd64

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $TargetMSI -OutFile $MSI

If ( $Tags ){
    $Expression = "msiexec /qn /i `"$MSI`" APIKEY=`"$APIKEY`" HOSTNAME=`"$HOSTNAME`" TAGS=`"$($TAGS -join ",")`""
}
Else{
    $Expression = "msiexec /qn /i `"$MSI`" APIKEY=`"$APIKEY`" HOSTNAME=`"$HOSTNAME`""
}
Write-Output "Commencing Installation"
Write-Verbose "Installation Command: $Expression"
Invoke-Expression $Expression

}
```

Comment: I assume the issue is somewhere in this block of code ...

Comment: $ChosenVersion = $Versions -eq $SpecificVersion <<<<<

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want a url for a given version? If so, this works:

```
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://s3.amazonaws.com/ddagent-windows-stable/installers.json"
$Version = $Response."5.14.1"
$VersionUrl = $Version.exe
$VersionUrl
```

Comment: I want to pass in a version number ... but what if I do something like

Comment: $Version = $Response.$SpecificVersion << would that work ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes. Though you could test this faster than talking to me.